# "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"? Is there any way to fix this?

Tags: c++

My compiler keeps telling me that "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"? Is there any way to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double randomgen(double min, double max) 
{
    double range = (max - min); 
    double div = RAND_MAX / range;
    return min + (rand() / div);
}

void generateWalk(double *data, int n,  double  T,  double  sigma) 
{
 double Delta = sigma*(sqrt(T/n));
 double X;
 data[0] = 0;

 if(randomgen(0,1)<0.5)
 {
 X = Delta;
  for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    { 
    data[i] = data[i-1] + X;
    }
  }
 else
 {
  X = -Delta;
  for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    { 
    data[i] = data[i-1] + X;
    }
  }
}

void ensembledata(double *data, int nperwalk, int nens, double T,double sigma)
{
    double *storer = new double[nens];
    for (int j=0;j<nens;j++)
    {
        generateWalk(data,nperwalk,T,sigma);
        storer[j]=data[nperwalk-1];

    }
    for (int k=0;k<nens;k++)
    {
        data[k-1]=storer[k-1];
    }
    delete [] storer;                                   
}

void meanvar(double *data,int size, double *mean,double *var)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double *first = data;
    int k = 0;
    for(k = 0; k < size; k++)
        sum += *data++;
    *mean = sum/size;
    sum = 0;
    data = first;
    for(k = 0; k < size; k++)
        sum += (*data - *mean)*(*data++ - *mean);
    *var = sum/(size - 1);
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(nullptr));
    double *mdata = new double[1000], mean = 0, var = 0;
    generateWalk(mdata, 1000, 10, 1);and record last position
    ensembledata(mdata, 1000, 1000, 10, 1);
    meanvar(mdata, 1000, &mean, &var);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3);
    cout << "mean = " << setw(7) << mean << ", var = " << setw(7) << var << endl;
    double sigvals[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            ensembledata(mdata, 1000, 1000, 10, sigvals[i]);
            meanvar(mdata, 1000, &mean, &var);
            cout << "mean = " << setw(7) << mean << ", var = " << setw(7) << var <<
        ", sigma = " << setw(7) << sigvals[i] << endl;
        }
    delete [] mdata;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I can't really think of which particular art of the code is causing the problem?

Comment: You could always remove bits of the code until you remove the problem, which should help identify where it's going wrong.

Comment: Your **compiler** tells you that?  That's some damn cool static analysis, or it would be if it bothered to report the line number at fault...  Also, did you try running your code under Valgrind or similar tool?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your syntax error ("and record last position"), I compile with a warning:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra    33218861.cpp   -o 33218861
33218861.cpp: In function ‘void meanvar(double*, int, double*, double*)’:
33218861.cpp:67:49: warning: operation on ‘data’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
         sum += (*data - *mean)*(*data++ - *mean);
                                                 ^
```

so I corrected that line to

```
         sum += (*data - *mean)*(*data - *mean); ++data;
```

Then Valgrind complains of a few writes to invalid locations:

```
==17852== Invalid write of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400D97: generateWalk(double*, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:35)
==17852==    by 0x40103A: main (33218861.cpp:75)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1df80 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400FE6: main (33218861.cpp:74)
==17852== 
==17852== Invalid write of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400D34: generateWalk(double*, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:27)
==17852==    by 0x400E23: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:45)
==17852==    by 0x401074: main (33218861.cpp:76)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1df80 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400FE6: main (33218861.cpp:74)
==17852== 
==17852== Invalid write of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400D97: generateWalk(double*, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:35)
==17852==    by 0x400E23: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:45)
==17852==    by 0x401074: main (33218861.cpp:76)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1df80 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400FE6: main (33218861.cpp:74)
==17852== 
==17852== Invalid read of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400E8F: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:51)
==17852==    by 0x401074: main (33218861.cpp:76)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1dfb8 is 8 bytes before a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400DED: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:42)
==17852==    by 0x401074: main (33218861.cpp:76)
==17852== 
==17852== Invalid write of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400E92: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:51)
==17852==    by 0x401074: main (33218861.cpp:76)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1c038 is 8 bytes before a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400FE6: main (33218861.cpp:74)
==17852== 
mean =  -1.199, var = 10231.199
==17852== Invalid write of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400D97: generateWalk(double*, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:35)
==17852==    by 0x400E23: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:45)
==17852==    by 0x401235: main (33218861.cpp:84)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1df80 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400FE6: main (33218861.cpp:74)
==17852== 
==17852== Invalid write of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400D34: generateWalk(double*, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:27)
==17852==    by 0x400E23: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:45)
==17852==    by 0x401235: main (33218861.cpp:84)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1df80 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400FE6: main (33218861.cpp:74)
==17852== 
==17852== Invalid read of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400E8F: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:51)
==17852==    by 0x401235: main (33218861.cpp:84)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1ff38 is 8 bytes before a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400DED: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:42)
==17852==    by 0x401235: main (33218861.cpp:84)
==17852== 
==17852== Invalid write of size 8
==17852==    at 0x400E92: ensembledata(double*, int, int, double, double) (33218861.cpp:51)
==17852==    by 0x401235: main (33218861.cpp:84)
==17852==  Address 0x5a1c038 is 8 bytes before a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
==17852==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17852==    by 0x400FE6: main (33218861.cpp:74)
==17852==
```

So there are three lines of interest: 27, 35 and 51.  You can probably see what's wrong with line 27:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    // Invalid write ... 0 bytes after a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
    data[i] = data[i-1] + X;  // line 27
}
```

Changing `i<=n` to `i<n` stops the code running past the end of the array here.

Line 35 is similar.  Line 51 has a different issue:

```
for (int k=0;k<nens;k++)
{
    // Invalid read ... 8 bytes before a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
    // Invalid write ... 8 bytes before a block of size 8,000 alloc'd
    data[k-1]=storer[k-1];  // line 51
}
```

You can see that the first time around the loop, we access `data[-1]`.  Changing `k=0` to `k=1` avoids that.  Or perhaps we need to change `data[k-1]=storer[k-1]` to `data[k]=storer[k]` to copy all values; there's insufficient commentary to understand what's intended.

Fixing those three problems gives a successful completion (other than a message "PAUSE: not found" from the shell invoked by `system`); I've no idea whether the output is correct or not.